# jQuery select first row in next table from last row current table

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors, row

How to select next row in next table with jQuery. For example I want go from link 2 to link 3 in second table.

```
<div class="panel">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="1.html">1</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="current" href="2.html">2</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="3.html">3</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="4.html">4</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

I use this script but won't select next row in another table and just work in itself table.

```
$('.current').parents('tr').next().find('a').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check for length of next row element in same table if not, then you can traverse to closest div `.panel` than  traversing to tr element.

You should also use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` to only target closest 1st ancestor:

```
var nexttr = $('.current').closest('tr').next();
if(nexttr.length)
   somehref = nexttr.find('a').attr('href');
else
   somehref = $('.current').closest('.panel').next().find('a').attr('href')
```